# Integral of $1/x^2$ using Riemann sums

Tags: calculus

I encountered a similar question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1909556/riemann-sum-of-1-x2), and one of the top answers involved changing the limits of the summation. I still don't understand how one is supposed to proceed after changing the summation, and getting $\frac{S_{2n}-S_n}{\frac{1}{n}}$.

However, for my question, I don't even know how to begin changing the limits of the summation.

> Question: Evaluate $\int^b_a x^{-2} dx$ using Riemann Sums.

The answer given is nice, but I was wondering if there was another way to do it, using the more conventional $\Delta x=\frac{b-a}{n}$ method.

Answer: Choose sample points $x_i^*=\sqrt{x_{i-1}x_i} \in [x_{i-1},x_i]$ by AM GM inequality. Then we have the Riemann Sum as:

\begin{align}
S_n=&\sum x_i^*(x_i-x_{i-1})\\
=& \sum^n_{i=1} \frac{(x_i-x_{i-1})}{x_{i-1}x_i}\\
=& \frac{1}{b}-\frac{1}{a} \ \ \ \ \text{(By method of difference)}
\end{align}

My attempt at a solution, letting $\Delta x=\frac{b-a}{n}$

\begin{align}
S_n&=\sum \Delta x f(a+k\Delta x)\\
&=\sum \frac{b-a}{n}\frac{1}{(a+k(\frac{b-a}{n}))^2} \\
&=\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{n(b-a)}{k(b-a)+an}
\end{align}

and after this I am stuck. Would my method have been feasible, and if so, how could I continue?

Comment: This question was closed but there may be some useful information in the answers/comments: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1909556/riemann-sum-of-1-x2?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: You can see how to integrate any rational power (other than $-1$) and thus any real power (other than $-1$) via Riemann summation in (the remarks of) my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4305837/815585)